# Reference for equivariant derived Künneth formula

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, cohomology, derived-categories

I'm looking for a reference for the following statement in as much generality as possible, assuming it is correct.

Let's $X$ and $Y$ be "spaces" with a $G$-action. We can take the $G$-product defined by
$$
X \times_G Y = X \times Y / \sim
$$
where $(x,y) \sim (g x, yg^{-1})$.

Let $K$ be a complex of constructible sheaves on $X \times_G Y$. Let $f: X \times Y \to X \times_G Y$ be the canonical map. Suppose $G$ has cohomology supported in degree 0 e.g. it is homotopic to a 0-dimensional space. Then is it true in reasonable cases that
$$
R\Gamma_c(X \times_G Y, K) = R\Gamma_c(X, f^*K|_X) \otimes_G^L R\Gamma_c(Y,f^*K|_Y)
$$
where the right side is derived $\otimes_G$, perhaps up to a shift in dimension? In particular, if $Y$ is a point, and $G$ acts freely on $X$, I'm hoping that $R\Gamma_c(X/G, K)$ will be the derived coinvariants of $R\Gamma_c(X, f^*K)$ up to a shift.

If anyone has some references regarding relationships between any of the above complexes, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: As stated, this is too strong.  Consider $G = e$ and $K$ a complex on $X \times Y$ that is not an external  tensor product of complexes on $X$ and $Y$.    E.g. $X = Y$ and $K = \Delta_* \mathbb Z_X$.

Comment: @PhilTosteson Yes, that's right. Your example shows it's too strong as stated. Perhaps I want a condition like $f^*K$ is the external tensor product of two complexes on $X$ and $Y$... Do you know of a good way to salvage the statement to get something generally true?

Comment: You could take $G$-equivariant sheaves $\mathcal F_1$ on $X$ and $\mathcal F_2$ on $Y$.  And use them to build a sheaf $\mathcal F_1 \boxtimes_G \mathcal F_2$ on $X \times_G Y$.  Alternately you could just consider a single space $T$ with a $G$ equivariant sheaf on it.  This isn't actually less general, because you can take $T = X \times Y$.

Comment: @PhilTosteson That sounds quite promising. Do you think you could develop your comment into an answer with either a reference or a short proof if you know how to show that statement involving the derived coinvariants? I would prefer if it's possible to use as much "standard formalism" (e.g. six functors) as possible. Thanks.